# Importing existing database

Tags: android, sqlite

I used this http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/ databasehelper class

then i made a adapter class

```
public class DbAdapter {
    private static final String LOG_TAG = DbAdapter.class.getSimpleName();

      private Context context;
      private SQLiteDatabase database;
      private DataBaseHelper dbHelper;

      private static final String DATABASE_TABLE= "MN1";

      public static final String KEY_CONTACTID = "_id";
      public static final String KEY_NUM = "Numero";
      public static final String KEY_NOME = "Nome";
      public static final String KEY_TIPO = "Tipo";
      public static final String KEY_LUOGO = "Luogo";

      public DbAdapter(Context context) {
            this.context = context;
          }
      public DbAdapter open() throws SQLException {
            dbHelper = new DataBaseHelper(context);
            database = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
            return this;
          }

          public void close() {
            dbHelper.close();
          }

          private ContentValues createContentValues(String Numero, String Nome, String Tipo, String Luogo) {
            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

           return values;
          }

          public Cursor fetchAllContacts() {
                return database.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] { KEY_CONTACTID, KEY_NUM, KEY_NOME, KEY_TIPO, KEY_LUOGO}, null, null, null, null, null);
```

I tried to run it bug it give that error " no such table: MN1: ,while compiling SELECT _id ecc"

I went to databases folder and actualy there is a db named MN1 whit the metadata table.

What's wrong?

EDIT

```
public class DataBaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

//The Android's default system path of your application database.
private static String DB_PATH = "/data/data/com.example.provadatabase/databases/";


private static String DB_NAME = "MN1";

private SQLiteDatabase myDataBase;

private final Context myContext;
```

Comment: post your DataBaseHelper Class i think you have a problem with the DB path.

Comment: i posted the first lines, other are the same of the code in the link

Comment: `no such table: MN1` you say you have a database with that name but does the database have a table with that name?

Comment: yes, the database exist, it is created by the helperclass but it isnt copyed from the assets